# If a death eater had sacrificed themselves for Voldemort - would that offer a protection to him similar to the one given by Lily for Harry?

Tags: harry-potter

Related questions:

1) [Why didn't James' love and sacrifice for Lily protect her?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/why-didnt-james-love-and-sacrifice-for-lily-protect-her?rq=1)

2) [Would Neville Longbottom Have Survived If Voldemort Had Marked Neville For Death Rather Than Harry?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7477/would-neville-longbottom-have-survived-if-voldemort-had-marked-neville-for-death)

It has seemed evident that the Order would rather capture than kill - especially Harry - as he himself says in the Battle of Seven Potters. So, it is safe to assume that all the Death Eaters will always be given a chance to live. And given the answers in Neville's case - it seems that Neville was expected to survive at least the first attack.

Now - in Goblet of Fire - Barty Crouch jr exclaims:

> "Tell me he told them that I, I alone remained faithful... prepared to risk everything to deliver him the one thing he wanted above all... you"

On another occasion - in Half-Blood Prince - in Spinner's End - Bellatrix claims that she would've given up her sons for the service of the Dark Lord

> "You should be proud!" said Bellatrix ruthlessly. "If I had sons, I would be glad to give them up to the service of the Dark Lord"

Assuming the same ruthlessness will hold true for herself rather than her sons - If Bellatrix - or Barty Crouch jr - had sacrificed themselves for the Dark Lord's cause - would he have survived?

Specifically - **Does the nature of a person's sacrifice affect the protection? Will sacrifice out of fear or dedication to their master provide a similar protective shield - even if it might be weaker?**

Comment: I don’t think the devotion or servitude of Death Eaters is comparable to the love of a mother for her child, but I don’t think I can find canon to confirm that.

Comment: What would be the value of this?  Remember Lily's protection wasn't a general purpose shield against everyone.  It was primarily focused on protected Harry from Voldemort.  The enhancements via Dumbledore, made it a bit more general purpose when Harry was at his aunt's house.  Who do you imagine that Voldemort would have needed that kind of protection from?  Would Voldemort even have allowed it?  Whenever he dueled Harry, he mostly ordered his followers to not interfere.

Comment: @Zoredache - agreed. But in GoF - Voldemort took Harry's blood to ensure that Harry lost a part of his protection. Having once lost all his powers to Harry - after creating atleast 5 horcruxes - wouldn't it be possible that he would want to be more protected? And anyway - I dont think Voldemort set much store by the life of his death eaters - as he killed Snape.

Comment: I don't think it's *just* about sacrifice, but also about love. From what I recall Dumbledore saying, the person making the sacrifice has to be doing so out of pure love for the person they are trying to protect, without putting up any resistance.

Comment: @TylerH If you can back that up with a quote or reference - I can accept your answer. I don't remember Dumbledore saying in any of the books that it has to be out of pure love.

Comment: Possibly related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55801/is-romantic-love-able-to-trigger-love-protection-charm/55805

Comment: @mustard I don't have an exact quote but there are many listed on the page about here: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Sacrificial_protection

Funnily enough, Harry was "saved" by a mother's love three times throughout the books, not just once.

Answer (score 9):

There is no unambiguous answer in canon.

- On one hand, we know that there's at least one person who both loves Voldemort ([including romantically - quote at the linked answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/115080/976)) AND would be happily willing to die for him: **Bellatrix Lestrange**.
- On the other hand, the sacrificial magic of love isn't really well defined in canon. Was Bellatrix's love of the exact kind and depth that triggered the protection? **We don't know enough from canon to say** (books nor interviews nor pottermore).
- On the third hand, Voldemort was effectively immortal, and there wasn't anyone who would have tried to kill him (the only 2 wizards who dueled him - Harry and Dumbledore - didn't ever try). So there was no conditions ever stipulated that would have allowed Bellatrix or anyone else to choose to sacrifice her life for V.

Comment: On the fourth hand, where did these two extra hands come from?

Comment: @Nit - Extrahandio Attachio!

Comment: I would think romantic love, which is what Bellatrix has for Voldemort, wouldn't be the type of love magic we are dealing with.  Parental love is what compelled Lilly and James to sacrifice themselves to protect Harry; parental love can't be broken the way romantic love can, which is why it's a much stronger basis for magic.

Comment: Wasn't blood a rather large part of the protection? So much so that it extended only for as long as Petunia was involved (at least until Voldy made the mistake of using Harry's blood for his resurrection thingy)?

Comment: @StanRogers - you're confusing sacrificial love magic, with the protection spell that Dumbledore made later on based on it and the blood ties.

Comment: Mmmm, don't think there's any confusion there at all. You're assuming the two are not interrelated, and there's no canon reason to make that assumption.

Comment: @StanRogers - the latter is built on the former. The former has no evidence whatsoever of having anything to do with Petunia

Comment: Lily was offered a choice. That's what gave Harry the protection. Rowling directly stated this too. Also you're wrong that only the two of them duelled Voldemort; on the contrary three others were duelling him moments before Molly killed Bellatrix: **Harry felt as though he turned in slow motion; he saw McGonagall, Kingsley, and Slughorn blasted backward, flailing and writhing through the air, as Voldemort’s fury at the fall of his last, best lieutenant exploded with the force of a bomb. Voldemort raised his wand and directed it at Molly Weasley.**

Comment: And to confirm that he was indeed duelling them before that: **Voldemort was now dueling McGonagall, Slughorn, and Kingsley all at once, and there was cold hatred in his face as they wove and ducked around him, unable to finish him —**

Answer (score 1):

Nobody loves Voldemort. His followers revered him. They don't have unconditional love for him, so the protection wouldn't work.

Comment: Wrong. Bellatrix does.

Comment: I am not comfortable with this answer.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To Barty Crouch Jr. appears to have actually loved Voldemort.

Comment: There were people who loved Voldermort as have already been mentioned.

Comment: As @DVK-on-Ahch-To says Miss Bella does. Rowling confirmed it - not that it wasn't all that obvious from reading the books... The problem is that Lily was given a choice and who would be giving one of his Death Eater's a choice: move out of the way or die? And who would be doing the killing? One of the trio or the Order? That wouldn't work at all and if it was Harry something else would be happening instead. Plus even if so it would require the person giving the choice to not only kill the shield but Voldemort himself. Do you see that happening? It wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely. Voldemort, or Tom M. Riddle, was conceived under the effects of a love potion, and therefore cannot love. There does not seem to be a canonical answer as to if that affects a love protection, but one can infer that it does.

Dumbledore told Harry that he had one thing Voldemort didn't, and that was love. Love was the reason Harry didn't die either time Avada Kedavra was used on him, and the reason he was safe in Privet Drive throughout his childhood (ignoring the fact that he was in an abusive home).

Again, pure inference: If Voldemort couldn't love, then he wouldn't be able to receive love and comprehend it. Even if a love protection charm did work, it would be unlikely to last long because of Voldemort's situation.

Comment: Do you have a source for the "conceived under the effects of a love potion"? I'm not doubting it, I just can't remember where to look for that information.

Comment: It was mentioned in one of Harry's lessons with Dumbledore.
(From the Harry Potter Wiki) "The fact that Voldemort was conceived under slaved love (Theorized to be a love potion by Dumbledore or to be the Imperius Curse by Harry)—administered/used by the witch Merope Gaunt to a Muggle—was related to his inability to understand love".

Comment: There is no evidence that it is the love potion conception that makes Tom Riddle void of love. And Bellatrix did love him so did Barty.