# Did Bellatrix Lestrange have any affection towards Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, when **Voldemort** tries to kill **Harry Potter** and **Harry Potter** travel to the Deathly hallows, that is, Kings Cross Station and he later comes back. There it has been mentioned that **Voldemort** had also fallen down and **Bellatrix** tried to support him to stand up as if she has some affection towards him.

> “My Lord . . . my Lord . . . ”
>
> It was Bellatrix’s voice, and she spoke as if to a **lover**.

Is it true that **Bellatrix Lestrange** had some affection towards **Voldemort**?

Comment: You can't blame her. He is too handsome.

Comment: Affection is a bit vague of a term to be sure. Can a complete psycopath feel affection at all?

Comment: @Voldemort I'm getting you either a mirror or glasses for Christmas.

Comment: I've edited the tags to make them match the question better, this is neither about the collective groups of death eaters or Voldemort but about bella.

Comment: @Voldemort Talented too. And who doesn't love a challenge to 'defeat' or 'win over'? Okay so he didn't have a nose and he had a pet snake but once you get over the looks it's not a big deal. Even Dumbledore - the only one you ever feared - suggested that you were the most brilliant student Hogwarts had ever seen even more than he was. He also said if you returned in full power he - Dumbledore - wouldn't be able to fully stop him. That's impressive is it not?

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To I wouldn't call Miss Bella a psychopath. Not completely anyway. Voldemort sure but not Miss Bella.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To Also it depends on the circumstances. And also the fact that many things can appear to be affection but they're very hard to separate if always even possible. Even so I would say Voldemort did in fact have affection for Nagini. I want to say Dumbledore even suggests something like this too. But for Miss Bella? No. Yet could Miss Bella have affection? Absolutely yes she could. And she did.

Answer (score 61):

**Yes, definitely.**

There are plenty of instances in the books of Bellatrix showing extreme affection for Voldemort. It's portrayed as an obsessive, unhealthy relationship, especially because he never returns her feelings. Nonetheless, she was definitely in love with him, as confirmed in by J.K. Rowling herself:

> **Did Bellatrix ever love her husband, or did she have love only for Voldemort?**
>
> She took a pureblood husband, because that was what was expected of her, but her true love was always Voldemort.
>
> — [*J.K. Rowling and the Live Chat* (July 2007)](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html)

Comment: *Unhealthy* relationship!? No!

Comment: Reminds me of Harley Quinn and Joker.

Comment: Helena Bonham Carter (the actress for the movies) seems to enjoy playing unhinged characters. See: Sweeney Todd, Les Misérables.

Comment: @Ellesedil, you should check out who directs most of those movies, then check who they are married to ;)

Answer (score 22):

A second confirmation from JKR, explicitly confirming that her love was romantic, and not platonic:

> ... And Bellatrix, was, as I think is clear-- you know, I doubt that people will be particularly shocked to hear, 'cause I'm sure they've deduced, **that Bellatrix is madly, *romantically* in love with Voldemort**.
>
> This is-- you know, that's the obsession of her life. And I believe that Helena Bonham Carter had to be asked to tone it down after she-- (laughs) The producer called me and said, you know, give me some background on Bellatrix so we can tell Helena about it. And I said, well of course, it's a sexual attraction. She's madly in love with this man, and obsessed by him. (laughs) Apparently, they had to ask her to bring it down because she was being a bit too sexy.
>
> (*[Anelli, Melissa, John Noe and Sue Upton. "PotterCast Interviews J.K. Rowling, part two." PotterCast #131, 24 December 2007](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/1224-pottercast-anelli.html).*)

Answer (score 20):

According to the newest story *The Cursed Child*, Bellatrix got more than we previously thought.

> DELPHI: I am from the future. The child of Bellatrix Lestrange and you. I was born in Malfoy Manor before the Battle of Hogwarts. A battle you are going to lose. I have come to save you.

While Voldemort doesn't love anyone, Bellatrix sure got exactly what she wanted.

Comment: I still have trouble as to... Voldemort. Doing something so... human.

Comment: Is "cursed child" even canon?

Comment: @Layna according to JKR it's canon [see this tweet](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/615498601809211393)

Comment: @Layna most or us ignore cursed child and jkr twitter

Comment: @Jungkook It still totally contradicts what was stated. Not just a bit but complete opposite. So whether or not she calls it 'canon' is irrelevant. Someone told me that she kept it that way because originally it was meant to be and she couldn't easily back out of it (something like that - or I'm mixing it up with another thing to do with CC). Either way it's absolute rubbish.

Comment: @MikasaPinata I don't have a problem with him doing something 'human' - I have a problem with him doing that though because he isn't one who would. But CC is bilge anyway so it doesn't matter much in the end.

Comment: @Pryftan agreed. The core of his character was that he was incapable of love.

Comment: @MikasaPinata True. But it should of course be remembered that having sex doesn't necessarily involve love. But still the closest thing to a companion he had ever was Nagini. He even pushed Bella away when he and Harry fell in the forest at the end of DH.