# Is there any source saying Voldemort and Bellatrix had affairs?

Tags: harry-potter

A friend of mine told me that Bellatrix is Voldemort's girl.

I argued that I didn't agree (because Voldemort never valued love) but he countered with the argument that even evil super-villains may feel the need to indulge their baser urges.

Are there any canon sources saying if Voldemort ever had a sexual affair with Bellatrix?

Comment: I think there’s a good question here, but it’s so crudely asked that I cannot give an upvote.

Comment: Since when do sexual attraction or activities necessarily equate with love?

Comment: @akexwlchan - Now with more innuendo and less crudity

Comment: If Voldemort really was a virgin at his age, it would just explain *so much*!

Comment: @phantom42 Why would such a powerful person limit himself to only one girl? Valuing love is inherent..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### **Yes (probably)**.

In [Harry Potter and the Cursed Child](https://www.waterstones.com/book/harry-potter-and-the-cursed-child-parts-i-and-ii/j-k-rowling/jack-thorne/9780751565355), we learn that Delphi was (probably) product of Voldemort and Bellatrix Lestrange, having been told so by Rodolphus Lestrange.

> As many of you know, a body has been found at Hogwarts. His name was
>   Craig Bowker. He was a good boy. We have no firm information who was
>   responsible for the act but yesterday we searched St. Oswald’s. A room
>   there revealed two things — one, a prophecy that promised — the return
>   of darkness — two, written on the ceiling, a proclamation — that the
>   Dark Lord had a — that Voldemort had a child. The news reverberates
>   around the room.
>
> We don’t know the full details. We’re only just investigating —
>   questioning those with a Death Eater connection . . . And as yet no
>   record has been found either of the child or of the prophecy — but, it
>   does look like there’s some truth to it. This child was kept hidden
>   from the wizarding world, and now she’s — well now she’s . . .

later

> **DELPHI:** *I am from the future. The child of Bellatrix Lestrange and you. I was born in Malfoy Manor before the Battle of Hogwarts. A
>   battle you are going to lose. I have come to save you.*
>
> HARRY/VOLDEMORT turns. She meets his eyes.
>
> *It was Rodolphus Lestrange, Bellatrix’s loyal husband, who on return from Azkaban told me who I was and revealed the prophecy he thought I
>   was destined to fulfill. I am your daughter, sir.*

Whether this is true (or not) remains to be seen, but this certainly meets the criteria for "highly-regarded rumours".

Answer (score 11):

**I believe they did not.**

Bellatrix definitely loved Voldemort (see my answer to [Did Bellatrix Lestrange have any affection towards Voldemort?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/63427/3567)), but Voldemort never cared for anybody else.

Two interview statements from J.K. Rowling that back up this idea:

> **Did Voldemort ever love a girl?**
>
> No, he loved only power, and himself. He valued people whom he could use to advance his own objectives.
>
> — [*J.K. Rowling Live Web Chat at The Leaky Cauldron* (July 2007)](http://the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/7/30/j-k-rowling-web-chat-transcript)

and again:

> **Has Voldemort or Tom Riddle ever cared for or loved anyone?**
>
> Now, that’s a cracking question to end with—very good. No, never. [Laughter.] If he had, he couldn’t possibly be what he is. You will find out a lot more about that. It is a good question, because it leads us rather neatly to Half Blood Prince, although I repeat for the millionth time that Voldemort is not the half blood prince, which is what a lot of people thought. He is definitely, definitely not.
>
> —[*J.K. Rowling at the Edinburgh Book Festival* (August 2004)](http://web.archive.org/web/20070204023349/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/news_view.cfm?id=80)

There is no mention in the canon of romantic or sexual affairs between Voldemort and Bellatrix. Given Voldemort’s complete lack of love or affection for anybody, this leads me to the conclusion that nothing happened between them, or between Voldemort and anybody else.

As a side note, your friend says “even super villains have d*ck”. I assume this is a crude way of saying that even super villains experience sexual attraction. I suggest he reads about [asexuality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asexuality).

Comment: Asexuality is fairly rare, is there any reason to believe Voldemort was asexual? Rowling's answers that he didn't "love" Bellatrix don't tell us he didn't have sex with her, there's really no evidence in the books one way or another (you wouldn't really expect there to be given it's a children's series).

Comment: @Hypnosifl I wasn’t saying that Voldemort was necessarily asexual, I was saying that the argument “Voldemort experiences sexual attraction because everybody experiences sexual attraction” doesn’t hold.

Comment: True. But I disagree with the definitive "they did not" at the top of your answer, since the Rowling quotes only cover the subject of love as emotion/caring, not sex. Do you disagree with anotherguest's answer? Namely: "The truth is there is no canon evidence to imply that he did. There is no canon evidence that he did not."

Comment: @Hypnosifl Fair point. I've revised the first line slightly.

Comment: @Hypnosifl "Asexuality is fairly rare" - So is being the most hated Dark Wizard in known history.

Comment: @Dason - Sure, but the fact that he's a hated dark wizard doesn't make him more likely to be asexual than any average schmoe. Being a chess grandmaster is rare and having six fingers on one hand is rare, but you wouldn't expect chess grandmasters to be more likely than anyone else to have six fingers.

Answer (score 7):

JK Rowling gave a [webchat](http://the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/7/30/j-k-rowling-web-chat-transcript) during which she confirmed Bellatrix's love for Voldemort...

> Isabel: Did bellatrix ever love her husband, or did she have love only for voldemort
>
> J.K. Rowling: She took a pureblood husband, because that was what was expected of her, but her true love was always Voldemort.

...and Voldemort's complete lack of love for her.

> Darchey: Did voldemort ever love a girl
>
> J.K. Rowling: No, he loved only power, and himself. He valued people whom he could use to advance his own objectives.

I suppose this doesn't preclude having loveless sexual experiences. But frankly, Voldemort doesn't strike me as the type to care about base mortal pleasures like lust when it could take time away from research into powerful magic and immortality. He certainly seemed to have no problem with throwing away his very good looks.

Voldemort was also deeply embarrassed about his own parentage, which was the result of a loveless union. On a psychological level, I can't see him intentionally emulating the father he murdered.

Answer (score 7):

I really feel that both answers are speculative but strongly claim that they did not, a discerning answer is needed.  Not that the question is whether he ever had sex and/or was frequently having involved with an individual.

**The truth is there is no canon evidence to imply that he did.  There is no canon evidence that he did not.**  Harry Potter is a world where the sex in the background is not shown to the readers because *it is ultimately written for children*. We know from canon sources that he never loved a woman, but sex may not equal love and for him to be a virgin, if he does have sexual feelings, would be out of character.

For many people, sex is about power and control. While he loves no one, those are two things he adores. This is especially true of "taking advantage" of a married woman as he is asserting dominance over husband and wife. Metaphorically, it serves same purpose when he took Malfoy's wand.

His father was taken advantage of sexually, that is for certain. By using someone else sexually he is not emulating his father; he is psychologically doing the opposite. I'm not sure that would actually come into play but it was in another answer.

He cares about power and immortality and (while he wouldn't love them) sex gives children and heirs (in someways) provide both. This is a weak argument though as he doesn't have any and the weak reflections of himself would likely disgust him. He probably feels that he is some form of twisted perfection of humanity and any *"dilution"* with another person would spoil that.

How is it out of character?  If he is not asexual, which is comparatively uncommon, he is a man who goes out to take anything he wants. If he has those feelings it would be odd for a character like him not to experiment with them.

Now as an adult, would it be advertised who he sleeping with?  No. He likes to portray himself as above the rest of humanity so if he takes part in a human vice, he will have no desire to advertise it.  Nevertheless he would not really care what those vermin think about him.  Also there is not Public Display of Affection(PDA) if there is no A. So would we know? No.

Would there be any reason he would pick Bellatrix? We don't know but I don't see that as the question.  He has no reason to assert dominance on her.

He may have liked to do so on other, more "feisty" individuals like Tonks or Ginny though.

Answer (score 2):

J.K. Rowling was recently [asked about this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O9aiVAFEsrg) during the European Premiere of *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*.

> **SnitchSeeker**: *Can I ask you a quick question about Bellatrix and Voldemort? Did They have a child?*
>
> **J.K. Rowling**: *I'm not- That's, that's off topic for this movie, sorry.*

<sub>(Note that this was long after *The Cursed Child* had been released.)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe that Voldemort was a virgin. I don't think he was ever romantic or ever in love with anyone but when he was young he was beautiful, dark and cunning and I'm sure he would have at some point used his looks to his advantage just like he used his charm to win people over. He was willing to do anything to get what he wanted and I'm convinced he definitely used peoples' lust towards him to his advantage.

Comment: Not bad but the question is about canon sources not self knowledge

Answer (score -2):

Considering Voldemort's nature, cruel and demeaning with a tendency to discard anyone who has served their purpose.... I really doubt any "romantic" or carnal relationship with Voldemort would be fit for a children's book or even supplementary material for a children's book. It would take the most depraved masochist to survive such an ordeal, and lets face it, everything about Bellatrix's character and even her name point to her being on the opposite spectrum, a complete sadist. She merely deludes herself in believing he sees any compassion for her.

Comment: \**sigh*\* I hate it when people talk about BDSM without having a first clue what they speak of. Ever heard of the term "Switch"? Plenty of switches are extremely sadistic but submit to a single Dominant and/or simply enjoy being a masochist in additional to being a sadist.

Comment: Also, leaving the fact that your real-life argument is 100% flawed, we also have tons of fictional examples of sadistic women willing to be a toy for a more sadistic master. Inanna/Anu in Weber's *Mutineer's Moon* from Dahak trilogy.  Elektra King/Renard from *The world is not Enough*. Etc...

Comment: I admit, it was more of an uninformed comment than an answer, but your comment does speak to the core of my point, the discussion doesn't really matter. Save it for writing erotic fanfic, it's all speculation.... And I'm all for VoldemortXPettigrew myself anyway... sorry for giving you that image... but it has about as much support as him and Bellatrix.