# Did Voldemort ever have sex?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

A comment on another question compared Voldemort and sex, which made me think of Sigmund Freud and JKR. We know that V. never loved anybody, but that says nothing about his sexual experience. Were fame, power, and artifacts the only things he lusted after?

Comment: Fame, power and artifacts are secondary to his real desire, ***immortality***.

Comment: Related, not dupe; [Is there any source saying Voldemort and Bellatrix had affairs?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65620/is-there-any-source-saying-voldemort-and-bellatrix-had-affairs/79764#79764)

Comment: It may not mean anything but Voldemort's relationship with Hepzibah Smith was sort of well irregular imo. The way she doted on him and how she was excited prior to tom's visit says there was something there. It might just be simple friendship between two people who shared a passion for antique items. Or It maybe that Tom took the relationship to another dimension to cozen things out of the old lady and to use her for his own ends.

Comment: +1 for thinking of this question before me :D

Comment: Judging by the amount of Mary Sue-like "Voldemort's daughters" in fanfiction he barely had time to do anything else!

Comment: @Yasskier - Fanfic, you say?

Comment: @Adamant it seems that one of the favorite past time for 13 year old girls is writing fanfics about various Voldemort daughters (usually Hermione is one). Eventually we might have a yaoi story when Harry is his son. I don't usually read stories but the "analyze bad story" kind of pages that help future writers.

Comment: @Aegon No. Absolutely not (as in it wasn't anything other than my comments i.e. your first part is true). That was him working his charm. Look at the way he manipulated her. That was his entire point. He made her feel special and that's a very good way to earn trust and unfortunately those who trust you are so easy to manipulate. Look at what the Riddle diary did to Ginny: he was sympathetic and got her trust but it was also only to manipulate her. **It was part of the manipulation.**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

JKR knows, [but she ain't sayin'](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/statuses/478984113404538882).

> **Q:** *Was Voldemort a virgin?*
>
> **JKR:** *Does a dehumanised wizard killer who murders in the pursuit of his own immortality forfeit the right to ALL privacy?*
>
> <sub><sup>Edited for clarity</sup></sub>

That being said, there were persistent rumours in the wizarding world that Scorpius Malfoy (Draco's son) was actually the Dark Lord's son via some time-travel nonsense.

> **SCORPIUS:** *The rumor is that my parents couldn’t have children. That my father and my grandfather were so desperate for a powerful
> heir, to prevent the end of the Malfoy line, that they . . . that they
> used a Time-Turner to send my mother back . . .*
>
> **ALBUS:** *To send her back where?*
>
> **ROSE:** *The rumor is that he’s Voldemort’s son, Albus.*
>
> <sub><sup>[HP and the Cursed Child](https://www.waterstones.com/book/harry-potter-and-the-cursed-child-parts-i-and-ii/j-k-rowling/jack-thorne/9780751565355)</sup></sub>

And Delphi (Lestrange) certainly believes herself to be the product of Bellatrix and Voldemort, having been told so by Rodolphus Lestrange

> **DELPHI:** *I am from the future. The child of Bellatrix Lestrange and you. I was born in Malfoy Manor before the Battle of Hogwarts. A
> battle you are going to lose. I have come to save you.*
>
> HARRY/VOLDEMORT turns. She meets his eyes.
>
> *It was Rodolphus Lestrange, Bellatrix’s loyal husband, who on return from Azkaban told me who I was and revealed the prophecy he thought I
> was destined to fulfill. I am your daughter, sir.*

Comment: She wasn't that squeamish when Dunderbore was concerned.

Comment: From a writer's perspective, I can understand why she doesn't want to say. Giving him a sex life makes him too human. Having him die a virgin makes him a laughing stock. That leaves her with [one option](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DGNZnfKYnU)

Comment: @DeerHunter She never said a word about Dumbledore’s sex life, only his sexual _orientation_. The two are completely distinct concepts.

Comment: @DeerHunter That's probably because she doesn't think that "squeamishness" is a concept that should apply when talking about whether someone is gay or straight.

Comment: It's not Scorpius, its Delphi.

Comment: "I was born in Malfoy Manor before the Battle of Hogwarts." Were there any signs of Bellatrix being pregnant?

Comment: @JAB - Nope. And you'd think Draco Malfoy would have mentioned it, given that his son was repeatedly mocked for being the Dark Lord's son. Clearly it was well concealed.

Comment: @JAB Exactly what I thought of. It's just nonsense. She can call it canon but if so it is completely contradictory to the book. And what does that say? It seems to me that it's more like a fanfic - and a terrible one at that. That Harry supposedly could be a Parselmouth after the soul fragment of Voldemort was removed from him is silly too - if I recall Rowling said he lost the ability. A good friend suggested it could be rationalised away by saying he just hadn't tried but you can only take this so far and all combined it makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 3):

Spoilers from Harry Potter and the Cursed Child

> yes, Apparently w/ Bellatrix

Here is text from the play:

> Delphi: 
>  I am from the future. The child of Bellatrix Lestrange and
>  you [Voldemort]. I was born in Malfoy Manor before the Battle of
>  Hogwarts.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

From *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*,  we know that
Voldemort had a child with Bellatrix Lestrange:

> DELPHI: I am your daughter.
>
> HARRY/VOLDEMORT: If you were my daughter, I'd know of you.
>
> *DELPHI looks at him imploringly*
>
> DELPHI: I am from the future. The child of Bellatrix Lestrange and you. I was born in Malfoy Manor before the battle of Hogwarts. A battle you are going to lose. I have come to save you.

Delphi speaks Parseltongue, looks like Bellatrix, and has prodigious magical talents, and so is probably correct in believing she is his daughter.

As such, he must have had sex at least once.

Comment: Assuming she was told the truth

Comment: @Valorum - All the evidence indicates that she did.

Comment: Well, her mother is a dangerous lunatic. It's certainly possible that Bellatrix was just lying.

Comment: @Valorum - Her ability to speak Parseltongue is what persuades me, frankly.

Comment: she can also fly, which she uses as evidence as well

Answer (score 1):

As Tom Riddle he was incredibly good looking and manipulative. He enjoyed playing with people and sexual encounters may likely have come into that. And don't forget he was a teenage boy. But I imagine after he failed to kill harry he lost what made him human and so was never sexual again.

Comment: Uh... I don't see the connection between "lost what made him human" and "was never sexual again." Sex isn't confined to humanity. It's kind of ubiquitous among living creatures.

Comment: Yes.. good looking and charming. The latter goes well with manipulation. Not individually but together; as it's so much easier to manipulate others if you can charm them, make them feel special, etc. The very suggestion that he's manipulative made him interested in sex is just wrong. I’m not saying he wasn't (though I seriously doubt it) but I am saying that the two don't have a correlation at all.