# Did Snape ever have coitus?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape

While reading this question [Did Voldemort ever have sex?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123245/did-voldemort-ever-have-sex) I thought of Snape’s version. He was desperately in love with Lily Potter (as we know by facts, e.g his Patronus) until the moment he died.

**But did that ever stop him from having coitus with another woman?**

---

I just got some more ideas to share. Snape’s obsession with Lily was because he was in love with her. Being in love could result from many reasons for a 15 year old. A very good explanation would be because he actually lost his virginity to her that’s why he was so obsessed to her.

Comment: The persons who down voted the question, I would like to explain their actions for future reference please. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect it was downvoted either because "urgh" or because it's obvious.

Comment: @Randal'Thor you mean its because i mention the word sex? what are we? prudes??? the answer is obvious for you really? then please answer the question, because i was sure voldemort never got physical as well, until i read the referenced question with JKR's interview....

Comment: @hedgehog I think it's just kinda pointless. (IMO), but I didn't downvote.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ pointless i wouldnt say because the answer to that would say a lot about snapes character.... because if he had atually coedus, then the whole story of loving lily etc etc would be jusst falling apart... and anyways its interesting to see how JKR wanted to shape the character....

Comment: and anyways it is suggested by the SE that when you downvote you should comment with the reason that you downvoted so the OP could maybe refrain accordingly.....

Comment: @hedgehog Exactly, you've just answered your own question. "*if he had atually coedus, then the whole story of loving lily etc etc would be jusst falling apart*" - therefore, by the contrapositive statement, he did *not* have sex with anyone else, because the whole point of his character is to be a dark romantic hero who only ever loved one woman.

Comment: Many people downvote questions they find uninteresting, unuseful, or to be questions of types they don't want to see on the site. I did not downvote this personally, but I understand the rationale for any of those three reasons.

Comment: @Randal'Thor it is indeed a contrapositive statement, but that doesnt stop JKR if she wanted to have him having coedus..... i am more interested on how JKR wanted to figure Snapes character rather than just learn if he had or not.... then it would be just stupid to ask.... but i aint asking for that reason

Comment: This question is fine, albeit strange. Just because Snape only ever loved one woman doesn't mean he never had sex; romantic love and sexual attraction are two different things. Unless there is a canon answer (in-universe or out) floating around somewhere, we have **no idea** if Snape died a virgin or not.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - it's not at all obvious to me, TBH. Mores of wizarding society aren't exactly clear-cut, on many dimensions.

Comment: Relevant (on Reddit) - [Did Snape die a virgin?](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/2s9k9i/did_snape_die_a_virgin/)

Comment: I'd be tempted to downvote, not because this is a question that involves sex, but because like many many other such questions, it involves sex poorly and for little reason other than personal amusement or thrill.  "It'd explain a lot" alone raises my creep radar by 9 points.

Comment: @hedgehog The question is Ok, it's just phrased in a creepy manner, show some respect to Severus, we all (almost) love him

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### No (probably).

There are no in-canon descriptions of Snape having a close personal relationship (sexual or otherwise) with anyone other than Lily Evans. Some time around her 15th birthday he managed to offend her and that seems to have been that. This obviously beggars the question...

### Did Snape sleep with Lily?

To which the answer is '**almost certainly not**'. There's certainly no indication in the text that he did and presumably if he had, the "*memories of Lily*" mix-tape he gave to Harry when he died would have included it. Awkward.

### Did Snape sleep with anyone else?

While it's not impossible that during his lifetime he didn't have sex, the reality is that he's portrayed as being **impossibly besotted with Lily**, to the exclusion of all else. Again, there's nothing in the text to support it, but the impression given is that even considering being with another woman would have been a second indelible stain on the perfect memory of his love for her.

> Dumbledore watched her fly away, and as her silvery glow faded he
>   turned back to Snape, and his eyes were full of tears.
>   "After all this time?"
>   "**Always**," said Snape.

Comment: Nice answer, though if I could contradict I could say that being in love and just have sex are two different things..So someone could presume that despite being in love with Lily after all these years that didnt stop him of having "fun".. I guess most guys in here understand what I am talking about... Damn, I want to ask JKR... :/

Comment: @hedgehog - My feeling is that he'd also see that as a betrayal of the purity of his love for her.

Comment: that is always the case man :) but if you come to think of it, there is actually a great chance he did, and thats why after all these years he still fealt guilty... maybe it wasnt only the love for Lily that kept him constrained maybe it was also the bad feeling that he "cheated" on her and thats why he was feeling so "bad" about it....!!!!!!

Comment: @hedgehog While this is possible, I don't see that strengthening his feelings for her nor is there anything to suggest something like that. While indeed sex and romance are separable, many romantics that are in love don't want or enjoy sex with someone they are not feeling in love with and are fine passing on any such possibilities. This applies even more so to fictional characters who rather than being realistic may portray certain ideals.

Answer (score -1):

**Possibly yes**

I never saw Snape as a virgin. It's actually sounds like a very weird concept.

First, people have sex for different reasons, not only love. Emotional frustration (he definitely had it) - to get distracted from his love tragedy. Experiments - just at least know what they are losing. Alcohol ending in regrettable (or not so) connections. Excluding physical relations from one's life completely is actually not so common in general and should fall under very specific individual state of mind. We can argue Snape was exactly such individual, but it's still not the first thing one would assume.

Remember it's a book for children, so the fact that we don't have any hints on Snape's sexual life may be not because he didn't have any, but because his experience was not appropriate to mention in the contexts of such books.

Also we should take into consideration the social group he was in. His school circle was all the teenagers with very loose moral behavior. He didn't have much of other communication and he desperately wanted to fit in. After all, he acted with Lily not the way he acted in his common life, he didn't care much about his morality when she was not near to judge him.

> "No - listen, I didn't mean - "
>   " - to call me Mudblood? But you call everyone of my birth Mudblood, Severus. Why should I be any different?"

I totally see him experimenting as a young man and being encouraged by the behavior of his school "friends" if nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

I think that he did sleep with Lily. Maybe it was only once, but he never forgot it. Lily was the only woman for him. He went so far as to lie to You Know Who and say that he had other women when he didn't. Even Professor Dumbledore was stunned to find that Lily was the only one.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. This answer would be a lot better though if you edited it to include one or more quotes as supporting evidence.