# What Happened to Rodolphus Lestrange (Bellatrix's Husband)?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* there is the mass breakout from Azkaban, Rodolphus and Bellatrix being two of the escapers. Rodolphus is very briefly mentioned (once) in the Battle of the Department of Mysteries.

> We’ll split into pairs and search, and
>   don’t forget, be gentle with Potter until we’ve got the prophecy, you
>   can kill the others if necessary — Bellatrix, **Rodolphus**, you take the
>   left, Crabbe, Rabastan, go right. . .

The last time Rodolphus is mentioned is in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, after everyone has made it back to the Burrow:

> “Bellatrix,” said Tonks. “She wants me quite as much as she wants
>   Harry, Remus, she tried very hard to kill me. I just wish I’d got her,
>   I owe Bellatrix. But we definitely ***injured* Rodolphus**. . .

After this instance, he is never mentioned again. Whether or not [he and Bellatrix had a "loving" marriage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63427/did-bellatrix-have-any-affection-towards-voldemort), shouldn't he have appeared again? Did Tonks kill him? Did he abandon his wife and escape Voldemort like Karkaroff? Why wasn't he in the Battle of Hogwarts? Did J.K. Rowling forget about him?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Did Tonks kill him?

Tonks is a trained Auror, and her estimate (that she only injured Rodolphus) should be relatively good: in any case, it indicates she was not using a fatal curse. Unless Rodolphus was knocked unconscious or lost his wand, even a fall should not have been fatal to him. And the Death Eaters seem to have been trying to keep their injured from falling to their deaths, as well.

> Did he abandon his wife and escape Voldemort like Karkaroff?

What Rodolphus thinks of his wife is anyone's guess--certainly she was in love with Voldemort, not Rodolphus. But it was their mutual loyalty to Voldemort that brought them together in the first place. Rodolphus was an old school friend of Voldemort's, as Slughorn's memory in *Half-Blood Prince* indicates, so his loyalty was probably personal as well as political. Rodolphus's actions after the end of the First Wizarding War are the best indication of his feelings in that regard. Voldemort had disappeared, but instead of breathing a sigh of relief and going on with his life (as Karkaroff did), Rodolphus joined his wife in attacking the Longbottoms. Yes, Bellatrix was probably the instigator, but other people seem to have perceived them as a team, and they went to prison together. Most people in the wizarding world consider Rodolphus a particularly hardcore Voldemort supporter. For him to attempt an escape at a time when Voldemort's power was greater than ever before would not make sense, and it would be inconsistent with his previous behavior.

> Why wasn't he in the Battle of Hogwarts? Did J.K. Rowling forget about
>   him?

Out-of-universe answer: Yes, I think there's a good probability that J.K. Rowling simply forgot about him. Many of the Death Eaters are essentially interchangeable (e.g., who cares what happens to Avery?). Rowling never gave Rodolphus much of a personality (unlike his wife and in-laws), so it is at least understandable that he disappears.

In-universe answer: There are a few possibilities.

1. He *was* at the Battle of Hogwarts, but he wasn't put into the same parts of the battle as Bellatrix was. Maybe his fighting skills aren't quite as good. Maybe he was needed to direct some other part of the battle. Maybe he was injured or killed early in the battle (Neville's Mandrakes come to mind), and so he isn't around for the fighting inside Hogwarts, which is when most of the other important Death Eaters are mentioned by name.
2. At the time of the battle, he is in some other part of Britain--or even in another part of the world--completing an assignment for Voldemort. When Voldemort calls the Death Eaters to Hogwarts, he can't come quickly enough to join in.
3. Rodolphus's injury was of a long-term or even permanent nature, rendering him unable to fight.

Hopefully, JKR will develop an in-universe explanation in the future.

Answer (score 16):

### He was sent to Azkaban

As of *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*, we have additional information about Rodolphus.

> DELPHI: It was Rodolphus Lestrange, Bellatrix’s loyal husband, who on return
>  from Azkaban told me who I was and revealed the prophecy he thought I
>  was destined to fulfill. I am your daughter, sir.

He survived, was sent to Azkaban (now more humane, being guarded by Aurors rather than Dementors) and released at some unspecified future time.

Answer (score 4):

As of right now (2015/11/13), nothing is known in main non-film canon.

He was never mentioned post-7-Potters in the books. He was never mentioned (in that context) in JKR interviews according to Accio-quote site searches; or on Pottermore, **although DH content is still in the future** so that may change.

Answer (score -1):

I think he tried to run away from Voldemort when he had his downfall  as Regulus Black did and Bellatrix found him and got a divorce because of his disloyalty and disrespect to Lord Voldemort. After it is possible he got killed personally as Regulus did in *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*.

> " Regulus black got killed for fleeing from Voldemort."

But why did Regulus get killed?

Well, he tried to overpower lord Voldemort by finding the Horcrux in the lake making Kreacher leave him to die after drinking the liquid in the marble bowl (shown in *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, that Dumbledore drank), ordering Kreacher to destroy it while he placed a fake in its place as the bowl refilled itself, Voldemort finishing him off.

Kreacher could not destroy it and Mundungus Fletcher stole it; later it was retrieved and destroyed by Harry Potter, Ron Weasley and Hermione Granger after nearly drowning Harry in a nearby frozen lake, whilst trying to retrieve the sword of Gryffindor that was taken by Ron (who also saved Harry after leaving for weeks leaving Hermione in pieces).

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! If someone edits your post for spelling and grammar improvements, please don't revert it back. I could understand if Jenayah had changed any of the actual content of your answer, but all they did was fix it up a little.

Answer (score -1):

i mean it says in cursed child that rodolphus gave delphini riddle (who was the daughter of bellatrix and the dark lord) A prophecy that would ensure that The dark lord won the battle of hogwarts.     So this must mean that he survived the battle of hogwarts and avoided azkaban. While it is unknown his feelings toward Bellatrix i find it hard to beleive he would betray the dark lord as he was one of his most faithful. I agree that J.K rowling definitely should have given us more information on him and many other death eaters. Personally i do not think he and bellatrix had a bad marriage, i mean they were both devoted to lord voldemort and worked together. Perhaps their loyalty to lord Voldemort made them closer

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please supply quotes to support what you're claiming.  If you're going to lean on the fact that Cursed Child says he gave a prophecy to Delphi, how are you handwaving away that he went to Azkaban which is mentioned in literally the same line?

Comment: This answer simply replicates information in the answer/s above without offering any useful additional information.