# If Voldemort had succeeded in killing Harry Potter, would he have gone on to try and kill Neville Longbottom?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

If Voldemort had succeeded in killing Harry Potter (when Harry was one year old), would he have gone on to try and kill Neville Longbottom right away, just to make sure he wasn't wrong in identifying Harry as The Prophecy One?

Answers based on canon only please.

<sub>Related: [Would Neville Longbottom Have Survived If Voldemort Had Marked Neville For Death Rather Than Harry?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7477/would-neville-longbottom-have-survived-if-voldemort-had-marked-neville-for-death)</sub>

Comment: Voldy isn't really the "just in case Im wrong" type. He's always right, isn't he? Because he is so powerful or whatever

Comment: well if harry had died, in that showdown where hes showing harrys "dead" body neville practically charges them by himself so i assume he would have died real quick if the protective magic harry put on everyone hadn't been working.

Comment: @DVK Are you asking before the events of the first book or after the Battle of Hogwarts?  I'm not sure it makes a difference.

Comment: and if you mean before the first book, then yes i believe he would have gone to the longbottoms house 2nd (it was probably planned) he had 2 reason to go their one to kill neville and 2 to kill his parents who were also strongly against him, we know they were a target and maybe even a planned target because Bellatrix heads to their place first stop after she finds out Voldemort is gone.

Comment: @tgnat - when harry was 1 yo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no canon answer to this question. However, in the spirit of canon, I postulate Voldemort may very well have tried to kill Neville when he was a baby, just as he did with Harry, to ensure he covered all his bases. Voldemort was far too egocentric to outright admit he *might* have made a mistake in choosing Harry as his nemesis, as the Chosen One from Trelawney's prediction; I think he would have gladly killed Neville as an example of what he might do to those who defied him, Neville being Frank and Alice Longbottom's son. The Longbottoms had been tortured into insanity by Voldemort's Death Eaters. Voldemort himself killing their innocent, baby son would serve to further assert his power in that he would be willing to destroy anything and anybody in order to preserve his control over the wizarding world. **So, yes, I believe Voldemort would have killed Neville as an infant, as a show of power.**

Comment: As my comment to TGnat says, the question was specifically when they were 1 year old babies.

Comment: I answered it accordingly ... I'm not sure what the problem is? (You're obviously free to disagree with my assessment). I bolded it, though, and added a few words. :)

Comment: I'd remove all the non-bolded parts, but now that you bolded the relevant one, it's much better.

Comment: Just wanted to be sure you knew the relevant answer was there all along. Your question doesn't specify you're asking about Neville when he would have been one year old, so until you clarify that that is what is important to you, I'm going to leave my answer as is. But then I'm happy to edit my answer. (And, yes, I see your comments about it, but it's still not reflected in the title or question). I'm not trying to be difficult, but I think if you're honing in on a specific factor, it ought to be reflected in the original question. :)

Comment: @DVK - I have edited my answer to reflect your more specific question regarding Neville Longbottom, and whether Voldemort would have tried to kill him as an infant. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I believe he would have gone to the Longbottom's house 2nd (it was probably planned). He had 2 reason to go their one to kill Neville and 2 to kill his parents who were also strongly against him, we know they were a target and maybe even a planned target because Bellatrix heads to their place first stop after she finds out Voldemort is gone. - whether or not he truly would have been worried about the prophecy after killing Harry, we do know that Bellatrix and others had the Longbottom's in their sight with hopes of reviving their master, which also leads me to believe Bellatrix at least knew of a piece of the prophecy or at least Voldemort was looking for boys born in July to parents who opposed him.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, according to me he will go to kill Neville as he is not sure that who was the one who have the power to defeat him. And Longbottoms were also very strongly against him just like Potters.